# Django Mail isnt sending anymore

Tags: django, email, smtp, gunicorn, django-email

I used to have a working system where all mails got delivered and everything worked. I didnt change nothing but now the Mails arent sending anymore. I checked the mail connection on another server and the same data still works and gets send.

Do I have an outdated version or something? How can I fix this?

This is my settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='email@here.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.myemailprovider.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@mail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MyPassword124'
```

views.py

```
    send_mail(
        'Test title',
        'Test Email.',
        '',
        ['my@mail.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

I am currently running a gunicorn server on nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I waited 10 hours, then removed the import of "send_mail" and added it again. After that everything worked like before. Strange.

I wish everyone facing the same error luck. Contact me for help.